# jqGrid DateTime sorting

Tags: jquery, sorting, date, jqgrid

How do you sort dates with time in jQGrid? I looked at the [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3apredefined_formatter&s%5b%5d=am&s%5b%5d=pmBlockquote) which states that I should use the "AmPm" function. However, I still can't get it to sort when taking into account the AM/PM, specifically in the *"Login Date"* field.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>My First Grid</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-3.8/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-3.8/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-3.8/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript"> 
 $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true; 
 $.jgrid.useJSON = true; 
 </script>  

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 

 jQuery("#list1").jqGrid({
  url: 'login-history.xml',
  datatype: "xml",
  mtype: "GET",
  colNames:["Role","Member Name","Login Date","Logout Date","Duration"],
  colModel:[
   {name:"Role",width:220, xmlmap:"Role"},
   {name:"Member Name",width:120, xmlmap:"MemberFullName"},                 
   {name:"Login Date", width:150,xmlmap:"LoginDateTime", sorttype: "date", datefmt: "m/d/Y h:i AmPm" },
   {name:"Logout Date", width:140,xmlmap:"LogoffDateTime", formatter:'date', formatoptions:{ srcformat:'m/d/Y h:i:s', newformat:'Y-m-d h:i:s' }, sorttype: "date", datefmt: "m/d/Y h:i:s" },
   {name:"Duration", width:80,xmlmap:"DurationInMins", sorttype: "date", datefmt: "h:i"}],
  rowNum:25,
  rowList:[25,50,100,500],
  viewrecords: true,
  loadonce: true,
  sortable: true, 
  altRows:true,
  height: "100%",  
  pager: jQuery('#pager'),
  hidegrid: false,

  xmlReader: {
    root : "DataSet",
    row: "Participant",
    repeatitems: false,
  },
  caption: "Login History"

 }); 
 jQuery("#list1").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{add:false,edit:false,del:false});
}); 
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <table id="list1" class="scroll"></table>
    <div id="pager" class="scroll" style="text-align:center;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Sample Data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DataSet>
  <Participant>
    <Role><![CDATA[Administrator]]></Role>
    <Organization><![CDATA[Test Org]]></Organization>
    <DurationInMins><![CDATA[46:44]]></DurationInMins>
    <LogoffDateTime><![CDATA[09/30/2010 12:26:55]]></LogoffDateTime>
    <LoginDateTime><![CDATA[09/30/2010 11:40 AM, PDT]]></LoginDateTime>
    <MemberFullName><![CDATA[IBM Test]]></MemberFullName>
  </Participant>
  <Participant>
    <Role><![CDATA[Administrator]]></Role>
    <Organization><![CDATA[Test Org]]></Organization>
    <DurationInMins><![CDATA[0:36]]></DurationInMins>
    <LogoffDateTime><![CDATA[09/30/2010 01:40:53]]></LogoffDateTime>
    <LoginDateTime><![CDATA[09/30/2010 01:40 PM, PDT]]></LoginDateTime>
    <MemberFullName><![CDATA[IBM Test]]></MemberFullName>
  </Participant>
  <Participant>
    <Role><![CDATA[Administrator]]></Role>
    <Organization><![CDATA[Test Org]]></Organization>
    <DurationInMins><![CDATA[16:39]]></DurationInMins>
    <LogoffDateTime><![CDATA[09/22/2010 01:48:05]]></LogoffDateTime>
    <LoginDateTime><![CDATA[09/22/2010 01:31 PM, PDT]]></LoginDateTime>
    <MemberFullName><![CDATA[IBM Test]]></MemberFullName>
  </Participant>
  <Participant>
    <Role><![CDATA[Administrator]]></Role>
    <Organization><![CDATA[Test Org]]></Organization>
    <DurationInMins><![CDATA[11:45]]></DurationInMins>
    <LogoffDateTime><![CDATA[09/21/2010 08:29:02]]></LogoffDateTime>
    <LoginDateTime><![CDATA[09/21/2010 08:17 AM, PDT]]></LoginDateTime>
    <MemberFullName><![CDATA[IBM Test]]></MemberFullName>
  </Participant>
  <Participant>
    <Role><![CDATA[Administrator]]></Role>
    <Organization><![CDATA[Test Org]]></Organization>
    <DurationInMins><![CDATA[45:35]]></DurationInMins>
    <LogoffDateTime><![CDATA[09/15/2010 09:25:06]]></LogoffDateTime>
    <LoginDateTime><![CDATA[09/15/2010 08:39 AM, PDT]]></LoginDateTime>
    <MemberFullName><![CDATA[IBM Test]]></MemberFullName>
  </Participant>
  <Participant>
    <Role><![CDATA[Administrator]]></Role>
    <Organization><![CDATA[Test Org]]></Organization>
    <DurationInMins><![CDATA[42:18]]></DurationInMins>
    <LogoffDateTime><![CDATA[09/15/2010 12:56:29]]></LogoffDateTime>
    <LoginDateTime><![CDATA[09/15/2010 12:14 AM, PDT]]></LoginDateTime>
    <MemberFullName><![CDATA[IBM Test]]></MemberFullName>
  </Participant>
  <Participant>
    <Role><![CDATA[Administrator]]></Role>
    <Organization><![CDATA[Test Org]]></Organization>
    <DurationInMins><![CDATA[5:45]]></DurationInMins>
    <LogoffDateTime><![CDATA[09/15/2010 01:52:43]]></LogoffDateTime>
    <LoginDateTime><![CDATA[09/15/2010 01:46 PM, PDT]]></LoginDateTime>
    <MemberFullName><![CDATA[IBM Test]]></MemberFullName>
  </Participant>
  <Participant>
    <Role><![CDATA[Administrator]]></Role>
    <Organization><![CDATA[Test Org]]></Organization>
    <DurationInMins><![CDATA[0:55]]></DurationInMins>
    <LogoffDateTime><![CDATA[09/21/2010 08:16:42]]></LogoffDateTime>
    <LoginDateTime><![CDATA[09/21/2010 08:15 AM, PDT]]></LoginDateTime>
    <MemberFullName><![CDATA[IBM Test]]></MemberFullName>
  </Participant>
  <Participant>
    <Role><![CDATA[Administrator]]></Role>
    <Organization><![CDATA[Test Org]]></Organization>
    <DurationInMins><![CDATA[0:49]]></DurationInMins>
    <LogoffDateTime><![CDATA[09/07/2010 01:10:07]]></LogoffDateTime>
    <LoginDateTime><![CDATA[09/07/2010 01:09 PM, PDT]]></LoginDateTime>
    <MemberFullName><![CDATA[IBM Test]]></MemberFullName>
  </Participant>
  <Participant>
    <Role><![CDATA[Administrator]]></Role>
    <Organization><![CDATA[Test Org]]></Organization>
    <DurationInMins><![CDATA[7:18]]></DurationInMins>
    <LogoffDateTime><![CDATA[09/07/2010 01:17:39]]></LogoffDateTime>
    <LoginDateTime><![CDATA[09/07/2010 01:10 PM, PDT]]></LoginDateTime>
    <MemberFullName><![CDATA[IBM Test]]></MemberFullName>
  </Participant>
</DataSet>
```

Comment: I want regular expression validation in add form of JQgrid. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 5):

You can specify Am/Pm using `A` - for example:

```
datefmt: "m/d/Y h:i A"
```

The AmPm mentioned in the documentation is the actual object loaded from the language file - but you do not need to worry about those details when defining your formatter.

Comment: I just noticed it now, but you may run into trouble with the time zone that is appended to `LoginDateTime` as the date formatter is not expecting it.

Comment: Thanks Justin. I tried that before, and it does work if I remove the ", PDT". I took another look at the jquery.fmatter.js and figured I should be using datefmt: "m/d/Y h:i A, T". However, this breaks the sorting that works without the time zone. Neither changing "PDT" to "UTC" or "Pacific" does not fix the 11:40 AM coming before 01:40 PM.

Comment: http://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/ed6eec0d1a522bf6e0f8ec6f15f2b22105249586

Answer (score 1):

The comma was not part of the regex string, so that's why it was failing. Taking a look at [this](http://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/ed6eec0d1a522bf6e0f8ec6f15f2b22105249586) git commit fixed the issue.

Comment: I want regular expression validation in add form of JQgrid. How can I do that ?